# create 2 dimensional array and fill first array with 1-variable

Tags: java

I am getting an error cannot convert int to int[], can anyone help please?

```
//Create array
int [][] studentResults = new int [numStudents][numExams];

//Fill 1st dimension with Student numbers 1 through numStudents
for (int count = 0; count < numStudents; count++)
    studentResults[count][] = count + 1;
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Trying to create 2 dimensional array.  Fill first with a number of students and the second with user input exam scores.  User can check on final grade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, if you want to assign a value to an entry in an array, you need to specify all of the instances for the array. I would suggest the following:

```
//Create array
int [][] studentResults = new int [numStudents][numExams];

//This loops through the two dimensional array that you created 
//And fills the 1st dimension with Student numbers 1 through numStudents.
for (int count = 0; count < numStudents; count++)
    for (int exam = 0; exam < numExams; exam++)
        studentResults[count][exam] = count + 1;
```

thereby iterating through every exam entry of `studentResults` for each student.

Comment: no need to set the other column value.. only need to set the first column

Answer (score 1):

So you need to set the value of first column of each row. As we know the first column index is 0. So for each row set the 0 column of the array like this

```
for (int count = 0; count < numStudents; count++)
    studentResults[count][0] = count + 1;
```